# новый массив по значениям

Tags: javascript

как мне суммирвоать массивы по значениям в них

вот у меня есть массив

```
[
    {"price":100,"amount":10},
    {"price":100,"amount":10},
    {"price":200,"amount":10},
    {"price":200,"amount":15}
]
```

мне надо получить другой массив из него

```
[
{"price":100,"amount":20},
{"price":200,"amount":25} ]
```

количество поменялось т.е. два массива сложились

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  { price: 100, amount: 10 },
  { price: 100, amount: 10 },
  { price: 200, amount: 10 },
  { price: 200, amount: 15 },
];
const imm= {};
arr.forEach(item => {
  if (!imm[item.price]){
    imm[item.price] = item.amount;
  } else {
    imm[item.price] += item.amount;
  }
} );

const result = Object.keys(imm).map(key => {
  const obj ={
    price: +key,
    amount: imm[key]
  }
  return obj;
})

console.log(result)
```

Как-то длиннова-то получилось, когда начинал - думал, что короче будет... но зато, понятно)

Comment: каждый раз когда используешь forEach вместо reduce, в мире грустит один @Grundy :-D

Comment: @Grundy, )))...

Comment: возможно немного короче: `arr.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
    if(!acc.map[cur.price]){
        acc.res.push(acc.map[cur.price] = {price:cur.price, amount:cur.amount});
    }else{
        acc.map[cur.price].amount += cur.amount;
    }
    return acc;
},{map:{},res:[]}).res`

Comment: спасибо большое , единственное забыл  спросить как теперь в этот отфильтрованый массив добавить еще значение "type":"buy" прсотите за нубские вопросы я только учусь

Comment: @Grundy, ну... это высший пилотаж)

Comment: все дотукал , спасибо огромное за помощь, карму не получается добавить , только зарегался, но пишут мол учитывается админами))

Comment: @nikblack, ты можешь отметить ответ выбранным, галочка рядом с ответом.

Comment: блин со вторым вопросом не разобрался , так и не поулчяается вставить третий ключ order_type из галвного массива